# copying classes linked together

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns, copy

I have few different types of classes which are cross linked (they contain pointers to each other - some of them vectors of pointers) and I am pretty happy with this design. But now it come a point where I would like to make a copy of all my structure and its very hard to correct all the links of every instance of the new classes. I already have a container class for all the structure but still the attempts I made to write a `clone()` method ended up in very dirty code and I am not satisfied with them.

I would like to know if there is a kind of design pattern that could help to solve this problem.

Comment: This is quite impossible without seeing your design; your description is very vague

Comment: I've run into a similar situation before.  What I did was to change to storing the objects in vectors and then using indices instead of pointers.  That made the copying quite simple at the cost of a bit more verbose code.

Comment: Please post at least some source code for at least a couple of the class you have and how they are linked together

Answer (score 1):

One solution that might help you (if I understood correctly from your rather vague description):

1. create a clone of all your objects (by now, just copy all pointers to the new objects still pointing to the original objects)
2. while doing so, keep track of which object is the clone of which object in some sort of dictionary (something like `std::map<void*,void*>` should do the job, but maybe you can come up with something better than the ugly `void*`)
3. go through all the new objects and redirect all pointers by the values stored in the dictionary

Comment: Yep, maps are my last attempt to solve the problem, actually the one who led me to ask here! It is probably not so bad, I just have to work more on it because the topology is complicated and I simply cannot have a very clean and straightforward code.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to keep some sort of a mapping form old to new pointers - before making a copy, consult the map to see if the object was already copied and if it is, return the existing copy, otherwise, call clone().

Something like this:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

typedef std::unordered_map<void *, void *> map_type;

template<typename T>
T *clone (T *ptr, map_type &m)
{
  auto p = m.find (ptr);
  if (p != m.end ())
    return static_cast<T *> (p->second);
  else
    return ptr->clone (m);
}

struct S
{
  int x;
  std::vector<S *> v;

  S *clone (map_type &m)
  {
    S *p = new S;

    // this is important to happen before calling clone() on subobjects
    m [this] = p;

    p->x = x;   
    for (auto q: v)
      p->v.push_back (::clone (q, m));

    return p;
  }
};

int
main ()
{
  S *p = new S ();
  p->x = 1;

  S *q = new S ();
  q->x = 2;

  S *r = new S ();
  r->x = 3;

  p->v.push_back (p);
  p->v.push_back (p);
  p->v.push_back (q);

  q->v.push_back (p);
  q->v.push_back (r);

  r->v.push_back (p);

  map_type m;

  S *x;
  x = clone (p, m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit cleaner if you can impose hierarchy (child-parent relationship) together with the links. Then you may approach cloning process recursively - let each of the parents clone all of all its children while being cloned and updating references.

In case you have relationship on the same level (say, objects being peers and cross-referencing each other in circle), you can artificially add parent that would clone all children, update its own references, and then update children with new references.

This would allow scaling/adding new components without modifying much of the code.

Comment: Hierarchy is almost there, but the problem is that the "grandchildren" have two parents. It would probably be pretty easy otherwise. I already have the "parent of everything", I just have to figure out how to let him do the dirty job :)

Comment: Why do grandchildren have two parents - do you mean each grandchild has parent and grandparent? If that is the case, parent takes care of all its children, while each child in turn takes care of all of its children - parent doesn't need to know if child has other children, child doesn't need to know if parent has other parents. Child should have clone method or something like that that he can propagate further to all of its own children and recursively return whatever is required. Whole idea of concept is to use recursion and do not keep any info other then direct-child parent relationship.

Comment: The topology more or less like tree: with a log, some branches and leaves, where the same leaf appear on two branches at the same time (in this way it has two parents). But I don't want to waste your time, I should have obtained enough hints to complete the code.